# why UITableView is showing data when I touch it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView loading some tweets, all works nicely but when I populate the table it doesn't enter to the CellForRow method til I touch the table view.... does somebody know how to solve this?

```
 tab = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, 400, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
 tab.dataSource = self;
 tab.delegate = self;
```

then...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"entra a cellula");
    Tweet *t = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }



    cell.textLabel.text = t.screenName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = t.text;
    cell.imageView.image = t.profileImage;
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Where is the code adding the tableview as a subview?

Comment: just after the tab.delegate = self instruction...  [self addSubview:tab]; however, the table is shown but void... just when i touch it it is populated...

Comment: Are you loading these tweets with background threads?

Comment: the tweets are already charged when i create the table...

Comment: What method are you initializing the table on? IE is this being done on the main thread?

Comment: it is called when tweets have finished charging... but the extremely weird thing is that it go to the cellforrow method til i touche it...

Comment: Please post code for the function where you create the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess based on what we know is that you aren't adding the table as a subview on the main thread. This means that redrawing doesn't occur until you scroll. Try wrapping the addsubview call in a GCD call like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
    [self addSubview:tab];
});
```

Comment: yeap I just solved it few second before with this function... but is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you finished loading your tweets call this method:

```
[tab reloadData];
```

to reload your tableView data source.